# Using MATLAB to compute fourier coefficients

Tags: matlab, fft

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6qqV.jpg)
Since I'm freshman of MATLAB, I'm not quite familiar with the functions of MATLAB and I wonder how to compute the fourier coeffiecients of these two periodic functions in MATLAB.

I tried to ask GPT but its code wasn't correct and didn't output the expected answers. I wanna get the correct answers like the attached photo.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBCVf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
T=2;dt=0.05;F=1/dt/2;f0=2;
t=-T-dt:dt:T;
df=F/length(t);g0=sqrt(dt/F);
x=cos(2*pi*f0*t);
f=t/T*F;
g=g0*abs(fftshift(fft(x)));
plot(t,x);
plot(f,g);
```

Here, `t,x` is the original signal `f,g` is the FFT signal, `dt=0.05` is the sampling time, `F=10` is the Nyquist frequency, `T=2` is the total time and `f0=2` is the frequency of the cosine.

Note that `f0<F`, as you already heard about, which is evident by looking the `F` range of the frequency plot.

Note here, that if you change `abs` by `real`, the result is the same, since this cosine is perfectly even. Change just one parameter, and you may lost this property.

Note `fftshift` is required to do the symmetrical shift magic, which is nothing more than shifting the middle or the array in the beginning.

Finally, what **EVERYBODY MISSES**, is the little `g0=sqrt(dt/F)` factor, which enables both `x` and `g`, as calculated before, to satisfy the fabulous [Parseval Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity), which means no other thing that the squared integrals of both signals `sum(x.^2*dt)` and `sum(g.^2*df)` are the same.

From here, you finally confirm that the FFT has units of `x/t` and the Fourier Transform `g` has units of `xt`.

Check the parameters and enjoy yourself from here.

[image]